# Resources seized at different times

Tags: anylogic

How can I simulate a service that requires different resources to be present at different times?
I know that worker1 is seized at time 0, and after X amount of time worker2 is seized. What blocks can I use to simulate the delayed arrival of worker2?

Answer (score 0):

`Service` blocks do not work this way. You do not prescribe *when* a resource does stuff.

You are trying to model resource becoming active at pre-defined times. However, in simulation models, resource become active when they are needed, which is driven by the model dynamics upstream of the `Service` block.

Unless you mean how to setup shift times for resources? In that case, simply learn how to define shifts for `ResourcePool` elements. Lots in the help and example models and tutorials :)

Comment: Thank U Benjamin. OK, I didn't mean to work with the service block. But with Seize-Release. i wanted to know if there was a method to call another resource while an action is taking place. I had set a delay for half the time followed by a seize to call the second resource and an additional delay to complete the job. However, this solution is not very smooth.

Comment: ok, please rephrase your original question and add some details, very confusing now ;)

Comment: It sounds like you seize - delay - second seize is pretty simple & straight forward.  You could also consider wrap up tasks, but those let the original entity go while holding onto the first resource.